# Windows Runtime Component Add As Link With Different Namespace

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I have been trying to create background tasks in my universal app solution. As separate Windows Runtime Component project is required to contain background tasks, I have add one to my solution. In the tasks I am accessing a class that resides in my shared project and in order to do so I use add as link. Although there seems to be no errors when I try to compile the project I get the following errors.

```
"winmdexp.exe" exited with code -1073741819.

Metadata file 'C:\...\BackgroundTasks.winmd' could not be found...
```

I believe it might be caused by the fact that the classes that I add as link doesn't have the same major namespace as background task project.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [Creating Windows Runtime Components in C# and Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230301(v=vs.110).aspx#DeclaringTypes), all public types must have a root namespace that matches the assembly name. I believe by adding a class as a link to my Windows Runtime Component project, I broke the same root namespace restriction and as the project didn't compile successfully metadata file was not created.

In order to solve this problem at first I changed output type of my project to class library and it compiled without a problem. Unfortunately background tasks didn't run when I tried to trigger them from lifecycle events.

So in the end I moved the classes that was shared between my "Shared" and background tasks project into a class library project and this solved my problem.